# How to retrieve data from server without any parsing?

Tags: iphone, mysql, objective-c, ios4

I am developing an application that heavily based on back-end data that comes from data base server. I am using mySQL server.

Yet I am getting data by XML and JSON parsing. But I want to know that is there any way or framework that makes possible to retrieve data with out any parsing like create a connection and then by a query we would get data in data set (like in .NET) ?

Thanks...

Comment: This should not be tagged `sql-server` as that tag refers to the database offering from Microsoft not a generic SQL database server.

Comment: can't you just store your xml data in a string column and just select it out like regular string data (thus no parsing)?

Comment: @KM : data are changing very frequently...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most of my XML parsing needs on iOS I use my `CWXMLTranslator` class, that is available as open source at https://github.com/jayway/CWFoundation. It uses a small DSL for translating XML into Objective-C objects.

Basically turning parsing XML like this:

```
<foo code="42">
    <name>Saturnus</name>
    <next_url>http://apple.com</next_url>
</foo>
```

Into a domain object like this:

```
@interface Foo { }
@property(nonatomic, assign) NSInteger code;
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString* name;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSURL* nextURL;
@end
```

Into something as simple as this:

```
NSArray* response = [CWXMLTranslator translateContentsOfURL:fooURL
                                       withTranslationNamed:@"FooRequest"
                                                   delegate:nil
                                                      error:NULL];
```

Where the translation would be a file named `FooRequest.xmltranslation` with contents looking something like this:

```
foo +> @root : Foo {
    .code >> code : NSNumber;
    name >> name;
    next_url >> nextURL : NSURL;
}
```

It's a bit more work that the *"automagic"* tools in .net, but simple enough to handle the most complex of SOAP or WCF.

There is an extensive `CWXMLTranslatorDelegate` protocol for handling **allot** more complex cases, and strange type conversions as well.

Answer (score 2):

I think you talk about native data type which will be accepted by iOS without parsing it to native structures. I'll suggest you to send response from back-end in **plist** format and on app level you can use it as native data object.

Comment: Agreed. If you can make your server return plist XML then you can use initWithContentsOfURL as described here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Granted you'll probably want to do a little extra work to handle asynchronous connections, but you get the picture.